# Unbalanced or misused parentheses or brackets

Tags: matlab, regression, spatial

I got en error message： Error:  unbalanced or misused parentheses or brackets.

for

```
d=sqrt(('T'(i,1)-'T'(j,1))^2+('T'(i,2)-'T'(j,2))^2));
```

I tried to add . or ./ but it didn't work.Any help please? I will be very appreciated! (T is a table I converted from a .txt file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, they *are* unbalanced .. and here is a trick to find out where/how: go through the expression recursively and textually replace every `(..)` construct with a..z, starting at the inner most and working left-to-right. Repeat until this process is no longer possible - what remains (or is missing) at each step?

```
d=sqrt(('T'(i,1)-'T'(j,1))^2+('T'(i,2)-'T'(j,2))^2));
d=sqrt(('T'A-'T'B)^2+('T'C-'T'D)^2));
d=sqrt(E^2+F^2));
d=sqrtG);
```

Or (and in practicality) use an editor with parenthesis highlighting/matching .. voting to close as a simple typo.

Comment: I followed your advice,and used radom numbers replaced every(), then I find out it started to show errors as long as I add (i,1) in the code: d=sqrt(('T'*1-'T'*2)^2+('T'*3-'T'*4)^2) was fine, but d=sqrt(('T'(i,1)-'T'*2)^2+('T'*3-'T'*4)^2) was wrong. Delimiter Matching is checked in Preferences and I'm sure I didn't type any parenthesis wrong. Which part of the code should I change?

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that the number of opening parentheses is different from the number of closing parentheses. And indeed you have one extra `)` at the end. Get rid of it.

```
d=sqrt(('T'(i,1)-'T'(j,1))^2+('T'(i,2)-'T'(j,2))^2);
```

Comment: Yes indeed, I found out  it last night, but I kept getting errors even I after deleted the last parenthese. As I wrote above, I tried to use random numbers to replace every (), up to d=sqrt(('T'*1-'T'*2)^2+('T'*3-'T'*4)^2) was fine, then I found out that it started to show errors as long as I add (i,1) back in the code: d=sqrt(('T'(i,1)-'T'*2)^2+('T'*3-'T'*4)^2), Error: unbalanced or misused parentheses or brackets. Delimiter Matching is checked in Preferences and I'm sure I didn't type any parenthesis wrong. How can I sovle this problem?